# Can I add a Custom Page Template through the Dashboard in WordPress?

Tags: php, ftp, wordpress

I am creating custom page templates for a client who came to me after drama with her last developer.  The new work has me creating a few custom page templates, and they work fine, but the problem is that her last developer is being spitefully slow with providing FTP information to the server that the WordPress site is stored on, and normally I would just upload the template via FTP into the theme folder in the content.  I assumed that I could add pages in the WordPress Editor in the Appearance section, but I was wrong.

Is there a plug-in or a method that I am not seeing somewhere on WordPress that will allow me to add new custom page templates through the Dashboard while I wait on the FTP info?

Comment: Looks like I will have to make a plugin, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WP Editor http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor/

Just use a text editor to create the new theme file.. and then use the Upload button in wp editor under appearance to get it in there. Also allows you to choose the directory so you should have no problems.

Let me know if this doesn't help

Comment: Wow this was exactly what I was looking for, a shame I didn't find this earlier!  Thanks.